# Two rows are overlapping in small device screen in Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am a newbie in Bootstrap. In Bootstrap, when I reduced browser screen to the small device size, the rows I used in separate containers are overlapping. Screenshots of the screens have given along with this post. Can anyone explain to me how containers are used without overlapping one another?

[Overlapping rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYhDc.png)

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
<title>WeGo</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class=".container-fluid shadow-sm">
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand h4 pl-3 logo-txt">WeGo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHam" aria-controls="navbarHam"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarHam">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><b class="sign-up-text">Sign up</b></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid cover-bg cover-style">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 cover-style">
            <div class="cover-col1-style">
                <h1 class="display-4 text-white">Your personal </br> travel assistant</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">Explore</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 cover-style">
            <form class="bg-white cover-form-style shadow">
                <h1 class="h4 text-center" style="padding-top: 1.3em;margin-bottom: 2em; font-weight: 600;">Sign in</h1>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control cover-input" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control cover-input" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check" style="padding-left: 43px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 110px;height: 50px; border-radius: 30px;margin-left: 9em;margin-top: 25px;">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h4 class="display-5 text-center pt-4">Features</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="card card-margin" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top feature-icon" src="./images/icons/location.svg" height="90px" width="90px" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text feature-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit iaculis dapibus. Sed convallis convallis justo,
                    id lobortis enim vehicula elementum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="card card-margin" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top feature-icon" src="./images/icons/food.svg" height="90px" width="90px" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text feature-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit iaculis dapibus. Sed convallis convallis justo,
                    id lobortis enim vehicula elementum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="card card-margin" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top feature-icon" src="./images/icons/hotel.svg" height="90px" width="90px" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text feature-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit iaculis dapibus. Sed convallis convallis justo,
                    id lobortis enim vehicula elementum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: When you define your grid by default Bootstrap will start from the smallest viewport. FIrst thing is you don't need to define .col-md-4 if you already have .col-sm-4 for example.

Comment: @MakisMilas I defined my grid as you said. But still, the overlapping issue persists. What will I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. The issue was I used two different containers which caused the overlapping of containers. Instead of two different containers, I used a container and two different rows inside that container which solved the issue caused before. Now the code looks like this.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRe3js3W69CrGF8kKXvvmYtT4zNGqicXRjvuAnmmbvPZXc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
<title>WeGo</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class=".container-fluid shadow-sm">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand h4 pl-3 logo-txt">WeGo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHam" aria-controls="navbarHam"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarHam">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><b class="sign-up-text">Sign up</b></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid cover-bg cover-style">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 cover-style">
            <div class="cover-col1-style">
                <h1 class="display-4 text-white">Your personal </br> travel assistant</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">Explore</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 cover-style">
            <form class="bg-white cover-form-style shadow">
                <h1 class="h4 text-center" style="padding-top: 1.3em;margin-bottom: 2em; font-weight: 600;">Sign in</h1>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control cover-input" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control cover-input" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check" style="padding-left: 43px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 110px;height: 50px; border-radius: 30px;margin-left: 9em;margin-top: 25px;">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h4 class="display-5 text-center pt-4">Features</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-margin shadow-sm" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top feature-icon" src="./images/icons/location.svg" height="90px" width="90px" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text feature-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit iaculis dapibus. Sed convallis convallis justo,
                    id lobortis enim vehicula elementum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-margin shadow-sm" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top feature-icon" src="./images/icons/food.svg" height="90px" width="90px" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text feature-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit iaculis dapibus. Sed convallis convallis justo,
                    id lobortis enim vehicula elementum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-margin shadow-sm" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top feature-icon" src="./images/icons/hotel.svg" height="90px" width="90px" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text feature-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit iaculis dapibus. Sed convallis convallis justo,
                    id lobortis enim vehicula elementum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEQenPMJNuqUwhg5W8UMFs66YBXrBVhhZzMFyRJVAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```